# Require.js Optimizer incorrectly ordering shim dependencies

Tags: requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

I have a web application that uses Require in order to load dependencies. I have a set of JS libraries that are included using the Require `config.shim` object.

Two such example libraries are:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    "libs/leaflet": {
        exports: "L"
    }  
    "libs/leaflet-dvf": {
        deps: ["libs/leaflet"],
        exports: "L"
    }
}
```

The second library, `leaflet-dvf` requires the first, `leaflet`. The second is a plugin to the first that depends on the global scope variable `L` that the first library defines.

When I run the application using Require normally, everything works fine. I can include either library from the shim, and everything works great. No problems.

The problem comes when I run this code through the Require r.js Optimizer. The Optimizer, when it builds the single optimized JS file, will incorrectly order the dependencies. In the built file, the `leaflet-dvf` code will come before the `leaflet` code. This causes a JS runtime error because the dependant plugin cannot find the `L` global scope variable that is required.

My build config looks like:

```
({
  baseUrl: "../js",
  paths: {
    "requireLib": "../js/libs/require"
  },
  include: ["requireLib"],
  name: "Main",
  out: "bin/Main-built.js",
  optimize: "none",
  wrapShim: true
})
```

When I run the Optimizer, using Rhino, it builds my output file. In the `Main-built.js` file, the code for the plugin will come before the required library. This causes an `L undefined error`.

How do I get the Optimizer to respect the dependency order of my Shims, in order to properly order the library files in my Optimized JS file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [requireJS sequential execution for non-AMD js files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914786/requirejs-sequential-execution-for-non-amd-js-files)

Comment: This is bit late, but If you have not solved this problem already, you need to use the shim inside your r.js config as well. that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back with knockout extensions and shim didn't work correctly. This is how we solved it.

Create a module called: leafletLib

```
define(["libs/leaflet","libs/leadleft-dvf"],function(leftlet,dvf){

    return leaflet;
});
```

LeafletLib has the main library and all of the extensions. On modules that have leaflet or leaflet-dvf as a dependancy you call leafletLib. It is kind of hacky but it might work for you.

```
define(["leafletLib"],function(leafletLib){});
```